# integration of Django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

Please kindly follow through the questions for my query.

A) Can mysql and sqlite3 run on same server concurrently ?

B) Currently I am  authenticating users using sqlite3 database. Was researching about integration of MYSQL and Django and found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04).

- So After performing the steps in the link,  Will  my django app be
     using MYSQL db ?
- Are these steps sufficient to move my database from sqlite3 to
     mysql ?
- If steps are performed as they are in the link, am i be using
     mysql db (but not sqlite3) through Django admin ?

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: yes, performing this steps ur DB will change from default Sqlite3 to MySql. follow [this](https://code-examples.net/en/q/7dc695) article

Comment: Answer A: You can't use MySQL and sqlite3 run on the same server concurrently, Answer B: Yes perform that steps which in your link you can use MySQL DB through Django admin

Comment: okay. but if i configure db as following and this is done after creating the superuser `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',    
        'NAME': 'automation_user',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}`  it give me the error **super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")** also it createsa file named **automation_user** in my main project directory. need help on this.

Comment: note:- my superuser name and passwords are different from the USER  and PASSWORD mentioned above.